# Writing a task to Use Swagger-Diff in Gradle.build to compare two Swagger.yaml files

Tags: java, docker, build.gradle

I need to write a task in `build.gradle` for my java project to use 'Swagger-diff' tool to compare two `swagger.yaml` files and make sure they are compatible in build process.

I've tried different approaches:

```
    exec {
        commandLine 'npm',
                'install', 'swagger-diff'
    }
    exec {
        commandLine 'swagger-diff',
                "$buildDir/resources/main/static/swagger1.yaml",
                "$buildDir/resources/main/static/swagger2.yaml"
    }
```

When I push my code, inside docker container logs I see it cannot find swagger-diff and build fails.

"

```
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'swagger-diff'"
"Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "swagger-diff" (in directory "/opt/xyz/pipelines/agent/build"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    ... 8 more"
```

Also I tried with `'gem'` and `'apt-get'` commands, I've got same result.

I am not sure if I'm doing the right thing or I need to use a library/command instead of swagger-diff tool for this purpose.

Dockerfile -

```
ARG DOCKER_URL=docker.abc.net 

FROM $DOCKER_URL/z-jdk-base:stable-8 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y swagger-diff 

VOLUME ["/tmp"] 

COPY build/xyz/xyz-service.jar /opt/service/service.jar –
```

Comment: What does your Dockerfile looks like?

Comment: ARG DOCKER_URL=docker.abc.net
FROM $DOCKER_URL/z-jdk-base:stable-8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y swagger-diff
VOLUME ["/tmp"]
COPY build/xyz/xyz-service.jar /opt/service/service.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use https://github.com/redskap/swagger-brake , which contains also a Gradle plugin for easy integration. 
Unfortunately I tested it with a quite complex swagger definition and it ended up with NPE and nowadays it contains only basic comparisons.